# How to set text in textblock in DataTemplate from CodeBehind and set this template?

Tags: c#, xaml, binding, devexpress, devexpress-wpf

I have this DataTemplate:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
     <DataTemplate x:Key="SomeCellStyle">
            <Grid Name="GridInTemplate">
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="2*" />
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                <Grid Grid.Row="0"
                      Background="#808080">
                    <TextBlock x:Name="ValueText"
                               Foreground="White"
                               HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                               VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                </Grid>
            </Grid>
      </DataTemplate>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</UserControl.Resources>
```

And I want to set this cell DataTemplate dynamically to column.

```
    var dataTemplate = GetCellDataTemplate();
    var dataTemplateObject = dataTemplate.LoadContent();

    var textBlock = GetVisualChildren<TextBlock>(dataTemplateObject).FindName("ValueText") as TextBlock;
    textBlock.Text = "test text";

    gridControl.Columns[0].CellTemplate = dataTemplate;
```

and GetCellDataTemplateFunction::

```
    private DataTemplate GetCellDataTemplate()
{
    var dataTemplate = (GetView() as MyView)?.Resources["SomeCellStyle"] as DataTemplate;
    return dataTemplate;
}
```

And template is changing, but the text is not being displayed. When I set text static in xaml template it works.

I want to do it in code-behing becouse I want to add columns dynamically and set different text in this TextBlock. So "gridControl.Columns[0] - where [0] is only example.

I know that surely it's a trifle..

Greetings

Comment: Merry Xmas, try reading this article it may help.. https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/wpfsdk/2007/04/16/how-do-i-programmatically-interact-with-template-generated-elements-part-ii/

Comment: Are you willing to explore other ways? if so you could try setting a datatemplate selector.